# Check the radio button Based on the value of variable in Ts object Angular

Tags: html, angular, radio-button

I have a scenario where i have a variable in TS file which hold the value true or false.
In HTML i have two radio buttons Labelled as true and false
Based on the value of variable,i need to check the radio button automatically. If the variable value is true then true radio button is checked and if it's false then false radio button is checked.

TS:
myvalue: Boolean = true

It's not working. Any leads will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: you have tried using ngModel?

Comment: Can you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)?